# swift: FB Fast Switching Between login

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

For some reason I cannot figure this out. I am trying to get the app to switch straight to the view after I click the login button. I have facebook installed on the device. However, at the moment it keeps opening safari first

## ViewController Action

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!)
{
...
}
```

FBSDKLoginButton refers to:

```
public class FBSDKLoginButton : FBSDKButton {

/*!
 @abstract The default audience to use, if publish permissions are requested at login time.
 */
public var defaultAudience: FBSDKDefaultAudience
/*!
 @abstract Gets or sets the delegate.
 */
@IBOutlet weak public var delegate: FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate!
/*!
 @abstract Gets or sets the login behavior to use
 */
public var loginBehavior: FBSDKLoginBehavior
/*!
 @abstract The publish permissions to request.

 @discussion Use `defaultAudience` to specify the default audience to publish to.
 Note this is converted to NSSet and is only
 an NSArray for the convenience of literal syntax.
 */
public var publishPermissions: [AnyObject]!
/*!
 @abstract The read permissions to request.

 @discussion Note, that if read permissions are specified, then publish permissions should not be specified. This is converted to NSSet and is only
 an NSArray for the convenience of literal syntax.
 */
public var readPermissions: [AnyObject]!
/*!
 @abstract Gets or sets the desired tooltip behavior.
 */
public var tooltipBehavior: FBSDKLoginButtonTooltipBehavior
/*!
 @abstract Gets or sets the desired tooltip color style.
 */
public var tooltipColorStyle: FBSDKTooltipColorStyle
}
```

## Clarification of Question

How do I get the app to detect the settings already saved in the facebook app and switch straight to the view?

I am new to doing this and I am slightly out of my depth. if someone could help me that would be awesome.

Comment: That is how it works on iOS9 and later. Nothing you can change. It was changed because changes Apple did to iOS9

Comment: @WizKid - ah... do you have any links for this so I can do some more reading? I mean is there any announcement about this specifically?

Comment: Apple removed fast app switch and made it so you have to click accept on a dialog. So Safari is a better user experience. I don't know where it is documented

Comment: @WizKid ok. I posted this as a question because here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9 it says on step 2 how to fast app switch but it isnt working

Comment: It makes Fast app switch possible. We don't use it for login.

Comment: @WizKid - Thank you